# Reverse SSH - Raspberry Pi and AWS

Tags: ssh, raspberry-pi, node.js, aws, reverse-proxy

I have a Raspberry Pi that is connected to the internet via a USB modem.
Due to my ISP, I unfortunately cannot get the public IP address of my dongle itself, and I get the actual cellphone towers.

I am trying to run a node server on the pi and I am required to access it externally from my network from, well, anywhere.

I have created an AWS AMI Linux server, and had reverse SSH on, but every time I try to hit the port on the AWS server to get to the pi, there is just nothing that happens.

At the end of the day, I have a node service running on the pi, that's behind a 3g dongle/Modem (Huawei E3531) that I CANNOT do port forwarding on.

I don't want to go through NOip, because that won't work for me. I have used Weaved, and it did the job, but the problem is going onto the site everytime to get the DNS for my device - which can change every 30 minutes.

Comment: FreeDNS, service created on Tor...

Comment: Are you certain your ISP actually gives you a public address you can reach from the outside, and not some internal address that is behind carrier grade NAT? In this case, no matter what you do, you won't be able to reach the RaspPi from the outside.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is the `-R` option or `RemoteForward` in `~/.ssh/config`. See `man ssh`. I am a bit rusty on this one, but I think:

`ssh -i ~/.ssh/yourAWSkey -R 80:localhost:80 ubuntu@PublicIpAddress`

should expose any webserver on your Pi listening on port 80 to the PublicIpAddress of the AWS EC2 instance. ssh portforwarding is very powerful and extremely flexible.

In addition to your question: Remote forwarding port 22 gives you ssh access to your Pi from the public internet *but be careful* - you miss SSH access to the EC2 server on port 22 (as long as the Pi is holding the connection). So you better do `ssh -R 443:localhost:22`. This will then forward any connection to PublicIpAddress:443 (the canonical HTTPS port) to the SSH port on the Pi.

Another additional point: you would want to set up a proper paragraph in `~/.ssh/config` along the lines of

```
Host ec2frontend
    HostName FillInThePublicIpAddress
    User ubuntu
    Port 22
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/FillInNameOfRSAPrivateKey
    TCPKeepAlive no
    ServerAliveInterval 15
    ServerAliveCountMax 3
    RemoteForward 80 localhost:80
    DynamicForward 8108
```

Whis allows a simple `ssh ec2frontend` to connect and reverse forward port 80.

And anothernother: You want to install [autossh](http://www.harding.motd.ca/autossh/) and use
`autossh -M 0 -Nf ec2frontend` to have a permanent connection. `autossh` is in the ubuntu repos and after installing and called with the above command keeps the SSH alive (with a ping through the SSH tunnel) and restarts if necessary.